# i5/OS PASE program not found or in use when CALLing QP2TERM

Tags: ibm-midrange, pase

i5/OS PASE program not found or in use. Path name is
  /QOpenSys/usr/bin/sleep.

I am getting this error on a system that had the PASE software installed recently. I need PASE for an application that is being ported to multiple systems, so I need to know how our admins can get around this issue. I did check this file for IFS locks using the API, and nothing came back. The listing of the folder shows some of these commands as SYMLNK, some as STMF. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzalf/rzalfpasecommands.htm), `sleep` is included as part of PASE.

Does the system have PASE installed?

```
GO LICPGM
10. Display installed licensed programs
```

Page down a few times, you should see

```
Licensed  Product             
Program   Option   Description
5770SS1    33      Portable App Solutions Environment
```

As far as `*STMF` vs `*SYMLNK`

*STMF is stream file, an object that's just a unstructured "stream of bytes"; basically every object on the IFS (or a PC, Linux, Unix) file system.  As opposed to the structured objects in the QSYS.LIB file system.

*SYMLNK is symbolic link, aka "soft link".  The actual contents of the object aren't really in the directory.    If you use `WRKOBJLNK DETAIL(*EXTENDED)` you'll have an option `12=Work with links` that you can use to see where the links point to.  For example:

```
                            Display Symbolic Link                     

Object link  . . . . . :   /QOpenSys/usr/bin/admin                    



Content of Link  . . . :   ../../QIBM/ProdData/OS400/PASE/bin/admin
```

Comment: It is installed. 5722SS1    33      Portable App Solutions Environment  ... I understand the difference between the two IFS data types, it was just very strange to have many of these commands point to another location. I would imagine this would be a local install, not something pointing to another location, or optical media (would that be possible?).

Comment: All of mine are SYMLNKs to `../../QIBM/ProdData/OS400/PASE/bin`  It's not strange.  AIX programs expect the programs to be in one place.  But for maintaining IBM i, IBM chooses to put them someplace else.

Comment: @Charles, thanks, but that still doesn't explain why I am seeing the error upon the call.

Comment: Seems like PASE isn't installed properly...try `CHKPRDOPT PRDID(5722SS1) RLS(*ALL) OPTION(22) `

Answer (score 0):

I was able to check both options 22 and 33, and both of them are showing as installed properly.

CHKPRDOPT PRDID(5722SS1) OPTION(33)
Product 5722SS1 release V5R4M0 option 0033 load 2924 correctly installed. Product 5722SS1 release V5R4M0 option 0033 load 5111 correctly installed. No errors detected by CHKPRDOPT.

CHKPRDOPT PRDID(5722SS1) OPTION(22) No errors detected by CHKPRDOPT.